# Getting indexes of search results

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, scipy

The code below gets the index of matching values:

```
x = ["Moon", "Earth", "Jupiter", "Neptune", "Earth", "Venus"]
get_indexes = lambda x, xs: [i for (y, i) in zip(xs, range(len(xs))) if x == y]
print(get_indexes("Earth", x))
```

The code below extracts the peaks satisfying the conditions:

```
intensitySortedPeaks = sorted(peaks, key=lambda p: p.Intensity, reverse=True)
for i in range(len(intensitySortedPeaks)):
    testMass = intensitySortedPeaks[i].MZ + 1.0033
    results = [p for p in intensitySortedPeaks if abs(GetPPMError(p.MZ,testMass)) < 10]
 ###how do we get the indexes saved as indeResults
```

How do I get the indices of the elements that were stored in the results variable. I want to remove those elements from the original intensitySortedList in the loop

How do I modify the above code to achieve this task?

Comment: explain it little bit more what exactly you want , and post sample output too.

Comment: I want the indexes of the search result so I can remove those elements in the original list

Comment: Where is search result and from where you want to remove , instead of comment update your answer with full info and post how your expected answer looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only want indices of matching items then try:

```
def indices_satisfying(fn, lst):
  return [index for index,x in enumerate(lst) if fn(x)]
```

If you want to remove the satisfying elements do

```
def removing_satisfying(fn, lst]:
  return [x for x in lst if not fn(x)]
```

Comment: fn is a function? Can you create an example with the planet list above?